# Angular tab controll change url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have tab [component](http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/ywUYQ/):

```
<body ng-app="components">
  <h3>BootStrap Tab Component</h3>
  <tabs>
    <pane title="First Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the first tab.</div>
    </pane>
    <pane title="Second Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the second tab.</div>
    </pane>
  </tabs>
</body>
```

and logic:

```
angular.module('components', []).
  directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        var panes = $scope.panes = [];

        $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        }

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        }
      }],
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  }).
  directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
```

After it I would like create event for change url after click without reload page, like this:

```
.../home?first
.../home?second
.../home?three
```

Help me please fix this issues, thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/ywUYQ/

Comment: @madalinivascu sir you have some ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here's a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgAerXX3t0528EiP62D9?p=preview) out of your code.

I have coded a custom `directive` named `action` to extend `click` on the `panes`.
The directive in turn has some function defined with `function\event name` matching with the `title` of each `pane`.

you can code your `route` in the action body by removing the `alert`

Happy Coding!

Comment: a downvote without reason leaves no scope for corrections

Answer (score -1):

please try this :

```
    angular.module('myApp', [ui.router])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
  }])
  // then define the interception
  .run(['$rootScope', '$urlRouter', '$location', '$state', function ($rootScope, $urlRouter, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newUrl, oldUrl) {
      // Prevent $urlRouter's default handler from firing
      e.preventDefault();

      /** 
       * provide conditions on when to 
       * sync change in $location.path() with state reload.
       * I use $location and $state as examples, but
       * You can do any logic
       * before syncing OR stop syncing all together.
       */

      if ($state.current.name !== 'main.exampleState' || newUrl === 'http://some.url' || oldUrl !=='https://another.url') {
        // your stuff
        $urlRouter.sync();
      } else {
        // don't sync
      }
    });
    // Configures $urlRouter's listener *after* your custom listener
    $urlRouter.listen();
  }]);
```